# How do you mark a struct template as friend?

Tags: c++, class, templates, syntax, friend

I have code like this:

```
template <typename T, typename U> struct MyStruct {
    T aType;
    U anotherType;
};

class IWantToBeFriendsWithMyStruct
{
    friend struct MyStruct; //what is the correct syntax here ?
};
```

What is the correct syntax to give friendship to the template ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
class IWantToBeFriendsWithMyStruct
{
    template <typename T, typename U>
    friend struct MyStruct;
};
```

Works in VS2008, and allows MyStruct to access the class.

Comment: Note that this gives all types of MyStruct access to IWantToBeFriends, it is also possible to grant specific specializations of MyStruct access.

Answer (score 7):

According to [this site](http://www.devx.com/cplus/10MinuteSolution/30302/0/page/2), the correct syntax would be

```
class IWantToBeFriendsWithMyStruct
{
    template <typename T, typename U> friend struct MyStruct; 
}
```