# Friend template functions (in non-template classes), C++

Tags: c++, function, templates, friend

If I have a non-template (i.e. "normal") class and wish to have a template friend function, how do I write it without causing a compiler error?  Here is an example to illustrate what I am trying to do:

```
template <class T>
void bar(T* ptr);

class MyClass  // note that this isn't a template class
{
private:
    void foo();

    template <class T>
    friend void bar(T*);  // ERROR: compiler gives me all kinds of grief
};

template <class T>
void bar(T* ptr)
{
    if (ptr)
    {
        MyClass obj;

        obj.foo();
    }
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2005, and the specific error I'm given is [error C2063](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7h7cw3t(VS.80).aspx), stating that "bar" isn't a function.  What needs to be done differently here?

Comment: Are you sure? I copied your sample code and it compiled without errors in VS2005.

Comment: It also compiles without error using G++ 3.4.5.
The code you show here is good. Perhaps the error is caused by something else?

Comment: your code is definitely right. the bug is somewhere else

Comment: I'll take your word on it and keep looking elsewhere.  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you mark a struct template as friend ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206045/how-do-you-mark-a-struct-template-as-friend)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure what you've posted gives the error? The following (using Visual Studio 2005) works fine for me:

```
#include <iostream>
template <class T>
void bar(T* ptr);

class MyClass  // note that this isn't a template class
{
private:
    void foo();

    template <class T>
    friend void bar(T*);  // ERROR: compiler gives me all kinds of grief
};

void MyClass::foo()
{
    std::cout << "fooed!" << std::endl;
}

template <class T>
void bar(T* ptr)
{
    if (ptr)
    {
        MyClass obj;

        obj.foo();
    }
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    int someObj = 1;
    bar(&someObj);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a workaround than a fix, but have you attempted to list the specializations as friends?

Comment: Yes, but as there are many potential specializations I'd like to avoid that.