# How to create friend structure in c++ builder

Tags: oop, c++builder, c++builder-2010

I am working with third party dll and using it's methods. As their funcs are not in TForm namespace I cannot use my structure written in my unit before class `TfMain : public TForm {}` definition.

tried

```
friend struct SVisDoc{
..
..
} doc;
```

Somehow I need to make it friend to be able to use from

```
void MethName(args) // not in TForm::
{
//I need to use it here
}
```

Looked at [How do you mark a struct template as friend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206045/how-do-you-mark-a-struct-template-as-friend) but during initialization shows an error.

How can I make my struct friend??

Comment: worked without making it friend!

Comment: please, provide us your way to solve your issue in a answer, and mark it as solution :)